# Forwarding Ensembles log with CDESetLogCallback

Tags: ios, swift, ensembles

I’m trying to forward Ensembles logging to my logger class.
But I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS on first call to CDELog

code for setting CDESetLogCallback :

```
    lazy var opaquePointerLogFunc : COpaquePointer = {
                let mutablePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<(String,CVarArgType...) -> Void>.alloc(1)
                mutablePointer.initialize(myLog)
                let opaquePointer = COpaquePointer(mutablePointer)
                return opaquePointer
            }()


    func myLog(message:String, args : CVarArgType ...){
            println(__FUNCTION__)
            //never gets called
        }

    CDESetLogCallback(self.opaquePointerLogFunc)
```

Comment: This isn't really an Ensembles problem as such, more a Swift-to-Objective-C issue. I don't have much experience with passing Swift funcs to Objective-C, but have you simply tried passing the function name, rather than generating a pointer type? Actually, looking closer, it seems you are trying to pass a method, not a function. I think you will need a func outside the class to make this work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Seems like it's not possible with Swift 1.2. I ended up writing ObjC wrapper.